# Möbius band-like strip

Tags: differential-geometry

A möbius band can be parametrized by the following

$
x = (R+r\cos(1/2\theta))\cos(\theta)\\
y = (R+r\cos(1/2\theta))\sin(\theta)\\
z = r\sin(1/2\theta)
$

with $R = 1, r \in [0,1], \theta \in [0,2\pi]$

However what is this manifold called?

$
x = (R+r\cos(\theta))\cos(\theta+a)\\
y = (R+r\cos(\theta))\sin(\theta+a)\\
z = r\sin(\theta),\\
a \in [0,2\pi]
$

When I plot it it looks like a möbius strip, here $a = 0$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here consider a curve $c_1$ $$((2 +\cos\ t/2)\cos\ t,(2+\cos\
t/2)\sin\ t,\sin\ \frac{t}{2})
$$ where $t\in [0,2\pi] $.

It is joining from $(3,0,0)$ to $(1,0,0)$.

Define $c_2(t)=2(\cos\ t,\sin\ t,0)$.

Hence Mobius band is $$ [c_2(t)-c_1(t) ]s + c_1(t) $$
 where $t\in [0,2\pi),\ s\in [0,2]$